# IMG not moving on webpage using HTML and JavaScript/jQuery. Is my code wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code I am using here is pretty much a direct steal from one of Code Academy Lessons. I really just wanted to play around with some of it on my own but nothing happens. The image doesn't load and nothing moves. My first question is the lack of an image loading the reason why nothing moves or can the broken image thingy still move?  My overall objective is for my objects to move when aswd is pressed.

Either way, here is my HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='small.css'/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sjs.js"></script>
        <script  type = "text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <body>
            <img src="F:\website\MiniWebSite\drillman1.png"/>
        </body>
    </html>
```

and here is my Javascript

```
//img url http://makepixelart.com/artists/anonymous/drillman //

var $img = $("img");
$(document).keydown(function (key) {
    switch (key.which) {
        case 37: // Left.
            $img.animate({left: '-=10px'}, 100);
            break;
        case 38: // Up.
            $img.animate({top: '-=10px'}, 100);
            break;
        case 39: // Right.
            $img.animate({left: '+=10px'}, 100);
            break;
        case 40: // Down.
            $img.animate({top: '+=10px'}, 100);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

I tried looking at other examples on here but I didn't see anything that looked like this.

oops.. forgot some CSS

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Edit More:

So I should have changed all of my code to reflect the changes I have made. I did crop my img and resaved it as a PNG. I can get it to upload when I run my file.. but I can NEVER get it to move for some reason... check out my changes. Thanks for all of your help. I really want to truly understand what I am doing and once i do I feel like I can help others. Thanks.

Comment: the source must be a valid image path, you're using a url to a webpage

Comment: But my IMG is relative..... and I am not sure what syntax error you are referring to.

Comment: @ChrisJones e.g, this is not valid: `switch(parseInt(key.which,10){`

Comment: It really isn't? So the whole code in http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-JwhI1/2/4?curriculum_id=50a3fad8c7a770b5fd0007a1    is bogus?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that URL takes you to a webpage, not an image.
This is the URL for the image you are looking for I believe:
http://makepixelart.com/peoplepods/files/images/1089856.original.png

But you may want to download the image instead and edit it since the png also contains a pretty large white background.

Comment: I thought I copied in the IMG math... oops.  Yeah.. I thought it was supposed to edit it itself like other pixel editors have... oops....

Answer (score 0):

The image src doesn't point to an image, just a webpage. That is the loading issue.

For the JavaScript it should look more like this

```
var img = $("img");

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var offset = img.offset();

    switch(e.keyCode) {
         case 37: // Left
              img.animate({left: offset.left - 10 + 'px'}, 100);
              break;
         case 38: // Up
              img.animate({top: offset.top - 10 + 'px'}, 100);
              break;
         case 39: // Right
              img.animate({left: offset.left + 10 + 'px'}, 100);
              break;
        case 40: // Down
              img.animate({top: offset.top + 10 + 'px'}, 100);
              break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I put your code in and then fixed the image so that it now points to a better version of the image. It still didn't move.

Comment: @ChrisJones I just updated the code to a better version. See if that works for you. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/CRYmk/1/ Also make sure that the image has position: absolute;

Comment: I feel like all of those changes should be there now.. but I don't see it working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I noticed, even the image not loaded error icon should move. Also there were syntax errors. Plus oddly this

```
$img.animate({left: "-= 10px"}, 'fast');
```

doesn't work but this

```
$img.animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
```

does

Also image position should be absolute not relative and you need to specify left and top positions initially. And please stick to either top or bottom and left or right.

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jx79G/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var $img = $("img");
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 37: // Left.
            $img.animate({left: '-=10px'}, 100);
            break;
        case 38: // Up.
            $img.animate({top: '-=10px'}, 100);
            break;
        case 39: // Right.
            $img.animate({left: '+=10px'}, 100);
            break;
        case 40: // Down.
            $img.animate({top: '+=10px'}, 100);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wsuXA/1)**

Comment: All you need to do is give focus to the window... Just click on it and it works...

Comment: I got it to work with seemingly everything but mine. Makes me wonder if the image type is messed up or something..

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run the 'website' from your hard-disk. Try setting it up [like a website](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ybn6Q92m4xg)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a jQuery conflict issue, try changing the following...

this:

```
var $img = $("img");
$(document).keydown(function (key) {
```

to this

```
var $img = jQuery("img");
jQuery(document).keydown(function (key) {
```